# installing scikit-learn-windows 64 bit with pip: Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I already already have a working installation of numpy and scipy. When I type

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

I get

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Don't type it in the Python shell; type it in a normal command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type it from a normal command prompt, windows PowerShell for example, not from python IDLE

Then you can use:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

or, if you are in the right directory, use:

```
./pip install -U scikit-learn
```